# Format Date from Wednesday 17th May 2017 to 17/05/2017 format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

The dates in my table are formatted like this `Wednesday 17th May 2017` and `Saturday 27th May 2017` and I want to convert it to something like this `17/05/2017` and `27/05/2017` and ORDER BY `MyDate`.

I tried doing it many different ways and did a lot of research for hours but no luck.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table
      WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN deliver = 'Completed' THEN 0 ELSE order = '$order' END
      ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(MyDate,"d-m-Y") ASC";

$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $row['MyDate'];
}
```

If someone could please help, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: thanks for help @GordonLinoff

Comment: when working with dates you should store it as DATE or DATETIME for better performance

Comment: for some reasons i had to use it this way, thanks anyway @CodeGodie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a proper format when converting string to datetime values

```sql
SELECT *, 
       -- convert to datetime and then format accordingly
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%W %D %M %Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') formatted_date
  FROM table1
 -- convert to datetime 
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(mydate, '%W %D %M %Y');
```

- %W - Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
- %D - Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
- %M - Month name (January..December)
- %Y - Year, numeric, four digits

Sample output:

```
+------+-------------------------+----------------+
| id   | mydate                  | formatted_date |
+------+-------------------------+----------------+
|    2 | Wednesday 17th May 2017 | 05/17/2017     |
|    1 | Saturday 27th May 2017  | 05/27/2017     |
+------+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Here is a [dbfidlle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8bc4d18942fb567e3151cf8c0948bf94) demo

Comment: you don't have to give me -1 for because your answer was not right mickmackusa. please help @peterm fixing this up.

Comment: @R.Shamon formatting of values in the question might've been a bit misleading. I updated it to make things clearer. But it looks like it's resolved now. And I'm glad the solution helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot @peterm.